# What is windows system path?-About Devcpp Opencv

Tags: opencv, path, system, dev-c++

I've looked into it through older questions and by using google, but I can't find an asnwe to my problem.

I have been trying to get devcpp to work with opencv2.1. I configured it with `cmake` and generated files. Then I compiled it with `Mingw32-make` command through a windows 7 cmd. Whichever way I tried to link stuff from devcpp, it's never worked. It keeps giving me `cv::freecast(void)` error.

I have seen some people talking about setting things to the system path. What is that system path exactly ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell Windows where to look for the openCV libraries when asked. There are two options:

1. Not to tell windows where to look for the .dll and put them in the same folder as the project
2. Tell windows where are the .dll by adding them to the system path

[Here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide) in "Compile using Visual Studio" point 3 you can see how to do it.